# Wordpress MySQL query fails

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
if (!$result2) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_numrows($result2) == 0) {
    echo("zero");
} else {
    echo(mysql_numrows($result2));
}
```

.. spent an hour on this, it should work but it doesn't, not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Should be using wpdb class to communicate with the database... http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb ,plus your query should work with the standard wp_query - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: No, this isn't inside wordpress, using it externally for another purpose.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is very ambiguous. *How* doesn't it work? And querying `SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter` would be more efficient than this.

Comment: did you get any error message ?

Comment: Should probably state that in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I just get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Â die() in`

Comment: That last space before `die()` is not a regular space, but the nonbreaking variety. Why PHP interprets that as part of the function name, I have no idea, but changing it to a normal space should fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re. your comment: Call to undefined function Â die()

It looks like you might have some non-ASCII character in the whitespace before your die() statement. Try deleting that whitespace and reinserting it, and maybe you'll find out what the database error is

Answer (score 0):

You should use query like this

```
 $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'";
 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Should be using wpdb class to communicate with the database...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'";
$result2 = mysql_query("$query2");
```

Double quotes in the query.

Without the double quotes in the query, the query will look like:

```
$result2 = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish');
```

Instead of:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
```